# Javascript : sorting an object by child object given key value

Tags: javascript

How to sort an object by a given value of its child keys ?

For instance, this object:

```
{
    "a": {
        "name": "Edward",
        "value": 21
    },
    "b": {
        "name": "Sharpe",
        "value": 37
    },
    "c": {
        "name": "And",
        "value": 45
    },
    "d": {
        "name": "The",
        "value": -12
    },
    "e": {
        "name": "Magnetic",
        "value": 13
    },
    "f": {
        "name": "Zeros",
        "value": 37
    }
}
```

would become sorted by the "value" key of its child objects:

```
{
    "d": {
        "name": "The",
        "value": -12
    },
    "e": {
        "name": "Magnetic",
        "value": 13
    },
    "a": {
        "name": "Edward",
        "value": 21
    },
    "b": {
        "name": "Sharpe",
        "value": 37
    },
    "f": {
        "name": "Zeros",
        "value": 37
    },
    "c": {
        "name": "And",
        "value": 45
    }
}
```

Comment: have you attempted to write code?

Comment: @Bravo yes, I will add it to this post.

Comment: @DevonDahon - did you forget to add it to the post

Comment: You can't really sort an objects properties - more reading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values you'd be better converting to an array of objects, and then sorting them

Comment: Sorry for the flag I misunderstood your question. But where is the point to order properties of an object? There is no use and is not possible...

Comment: I take it, @DevonDahon you haven't tried at all - answer given, with caveat

Comment: @Bravo What I actually tried (and which works as well) is to add the key of each child object to itself, then convert the parent object to a `foo` array, sort it with `foo.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)` and recreate the object.

Comment: yeah, don't know what you mean - anyway, answer posted, don't rely on it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Comment: Thanks @MickaelB. but the post you mentioned concerns an array, not an object

Comment: @DevonDahon object can not be sorted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```js
var obj = {
    "a": {
        "name": "Edward",
        "value": 21
    },
    "b": {
        "name": "Sharpe",
        "value": 37
    },
    "c": {
        "name": "And",
        "value": 45
    },
    "d": {
        "name": "The",
        "value": -12
    },
    "e": {
        "name": "Magnetic",
        "value": 13
    },
    "f": {
        "name": "Zeros",
        "value": 37
    }
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort(([,{value:a}],[,{value:b}])=>a-b));
console.log(result);
console.log(Object.keys(result).join());
```

but while this seems to work, object property order is not strictly defined, so whose to say it will always work

for example, if some of the top level keys are numeric, this is the result

```js
var obj = {
    "a": {
        "name": "Edward",
        "value": 21
    },
    "b": {
        "name": "Sharpe",
        "value": 37
    },
    "1": {
        "name": "And",
        "value": 45
    },
    "d": {
        "name": "The",
        "value": -12
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "Magnetic",
        "value": 13
    },
    "f": {
        "name": "Zeros",
        "value": 37
    }
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort(([,{value:a}],[,{value:b}])=>a-b));
console.log(result);
console.log(Object.keys(result).join()); // want d2abf1 - get 12dabf
```

this is because numeric keys ALWAYS precede non-numeric, regardless of creation order  - thats one thing that IS defined about object property order